# Broken slideshow in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, validation, cross-browser, compatibility

can you tell me where's the problem with my code in IE?

http://dv-projects.bluefile.cz/huno/

Slideshow does not work. Seems like a problem with CSS.

[image: http://i44.tinypic.com/2q9exk4.png]

IE version: 11.0.2

HTML:

```
<div class="slider-wrapper">
            <article class="slider">
                <div class="slide-1">
                    <div class="slider-image"></div>
                    <div class="slider-info">
                        <h2>Nový produkt v nabídce</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="slider-button"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-2">
                    <div class="slider-image"></div>
                    <div class="slider-info">
                        <h2>Novinka na trhu!</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="slider-button"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide-3">
                    <div class="slider-image"></div>
                    <div class="slider-info">
                        <h2>Kvalita a spolehlivost zaručena</h2>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum...
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slider-radio-buttons">
                    <div class="on slide1"></div>
                    <div class="off slide2"></div>
                    <div class="off slide3"></div>
                </div>
            </article>
        </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't like to your website. Post your code here. It works perfectly, you just forgot to use Cross Browser opacity in your CSS.

Comment: Please share which version of IE you're having issues with as well; older versions of IE are radically different than modern versions.

Comment: remove this line from your HTML `<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->`

Comment: Sorry but there's not enough to go on. "Slideshow" is ambiguous for a start. If you mean the carousel/slider thing with the class="slider" then that appears to be working fine. Unless it's supposed to be automated. In which case I'd suspect a javascript problem not a CSS one.

Comment: @SurjithSM That line shouldn't cause any problems. It's a comment, and the page still loads in Standards mode.

Comment: @JonathanSampson For me, It loads in Quirks mode in IE9

Comment: @SurjithSM You're right; that line appears to be breaking the doctype in IE9. Just one of the many radical differences between old IE, and modern IE. As pointed out in my answer below, this doesn't need to be *removed*; just moved below the doctype.

Comment: I think I need this line to stop IE blocking my jQuery library.

Comment: @DesVal Move it below your doctype, as stated in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements aren't affected by the parents opacity being set to 0. In order to resolve this, set the opacity on the children to "inherit":

```css
.slider-image, 
.slider-info {
    opacity: inherit;
}
```

This appears to have resolved the issue for me in IE11.

As was pointed out in the comments above, your document is getting loaded into Quirks mode in some older versions of Internet Explorer. It appears to be the result of the [Mark of the Web](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628%28v=vs.85%29.ASPX):

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

This should go *below* your Doctype, as demonstrated in the linked documentation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<html>
```